# Script change inner HTML not working

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following script, to change the inner HTML, but it is not working.
What am I missing here?

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var allElements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("benkopte-specs-list");
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var text = allElements[i].innerHTML;
    if (text == 'Ja') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>";
    }
    if (text == 'Yes') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>";
    }
    if (text == 'Nee') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "<i class='icon-specs-nee'></i>";
    }
    if (text == 'No') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "<i class='icon-specs-nee'></i>";
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="benkopte-specs-list">
<li><span class="specs-info-front">WiFi</span>Ja <span class="specs-info-last">WiFi</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try using Developer Tools?

Comment: You are looking at the innerhtml of the ul not the li's. Even then it should be looking to see if it cantains the string rather than strict equals or will never match. Use the debugger to step through and inspect your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is to replace the words `Ja`, `Yes` etc with their `<i>` counterparts. Here's how you'll achieve that:

```js
var allElements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("benkopte-specs-list");
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var text = allElements[i].innerHTML;
    
    console.log(text)
    if (text.indexOf('Ja') > -1) {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = text.replace("Ja", "<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>");
    }
    if (text.indexOf('Yes') > -1) {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = text.replace("Yes", "<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>");
    }
    if (text.indexOf('Nee') > -1) {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = text.replace("Nee", "<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>");
    }
    if (text.indexOf('No') > -1) {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = text.replace("No", "<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>");
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="benkopte-specs-list">
  <li><span class="specs-info-front">WiFi</span>Ja <span class="specs-info-last">WiFi</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here, `Ja` has been replaced by `<i class='icon-specs-ja'></i>` in the html.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing to see if the `innerHTML` *equals* a value instead of checking to see if it "*contains*" that value.

Also, you are not querying for the right thing. You should query for the `span` that comes just before the text you want to test, not the `ul` because that causes you to get the entire HTML string that it contains and that's not what you want.

Next, `getElementsByClassName()` certainly works, but because it returns a "live" node list, there are performance implications to using it. Generally, use `querySelectorAll()` instead.

Also, since you seem to want the same output for "Yes" and "Ja" and for "No" and "Nee", you can condense the `if/then` statements to two.

```js
// Search for the span that comes right before the text you want
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".benkopte-specs-list .specs-info-front");
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {

    // Get the text (not HTML) of the following node
    var text = allElements[i].nextSibling.textContent;
    
    console.log("Old content was: " + allElements[i].nextSibling.textContent);
    
    // Even now that the correct text is being searched, it may be better to check for
    // contents than an exact match as you also have spaces in the text
    // string.indexOf(pattern) returns -1 if the pattern is not found within the string
    
    // There are two values that will result in one class, so test for either of them
    if (text.indexOf('Ja') > -1 || text.indexOf('Yes') > -1) {
        allElements[i].nextSibling.innerHTML = "<i class='icon-specs-ja'>" + text + "</i>";
    }

    // There are two values that will result in one class, so test for either of them
    if (text.indexOf('Nee') > -1 || text.indexOf('No') > -1) {
        allElements[i].nextSibling.innerHTML = "<i class='icon-specs-nee'>" + text + "</i>";
    }

    console.log("New content is: " + allElements[i].nextSibling.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul class="benkopte-specs-list">
  <li><span class="specs-info-front">WiFi</span>Ja <span class="specs-info-last">WiFi</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion, but that still does not change the inner HTML.

Comment: @HenkZ It is changing the `innerHTML`, it's just that you have only supplied an empty element, so there is no visible output. You need to tell us what should be replaced and with what.